# How can I do if statement in css?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am developing a website in wordpress but I am using a builder call Divi. In this builder I can have custom css code but not java.

How can I do something like this but purely in css:

```
if heigh-res > 1000 then
    padding-top: 200px;
```

For those that have marked my question as a duplicate, it is not. The question that you think I have duplicated asks about changing the .css file that is loaded depending on the screen resolution. I am not asking about changing the file but I am asking about setting padding if the screen height is greater than 1000px.

Comment: Try googling *"CSS media queries"*

Comment: you need css preprocessor，such as sass or less.

Comment: No, a css preprocessor won't know the resolution of the screen

Comment: @jonrsharpe either we close as dupe or you make that an answer, that's the right solution

Comment: This question has already answers. visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446812/css-equivalent-of-the-if-statement

Comment: Because I am using a builder in wordpress, the builder only allows for custom css code and I cannot use and preprocessor.

Comment: @jonrsharpe well found!

Comment: can i use something like:

    @media screen and (min-height: 1000px) {
    body {
        padding-top: 200px;
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using media queries and set min-width as you want.
Here an example.

```
<style>
@media (min-width : 1000px) {
.your_class {
padding-top: 200px;
}
}
</style>
```

Comment: what do you mean by .your_class?

Comment: .your_class is the class that you are using in rour html code 
Ex: <div class=" your_class" > </div>