# Resizing image base on the longest side

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to find a method to re-size image (.jpg) file base on the longest side. Images taken vertically and horizontally will have different longest side, I'm trying to fit them into a size-fixed div (inline-block). If I control only width or length, they will not be in scale (squashed).

I have read "[CSS Equivalent of the “if” statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446812/css-equivalent-of-the-if-statement)", it seems that there is a similar/possible method I can go about... finding which is the longest side (width OR height) and then adding 2 css for that.

Perhaps something along the lines below?
(Page is HTML based)

CSS

```
img.thumb { identify longest side} //not quite sure how to go about this

img.thumb width {
  width:200px;
  height:auto;
  border:0px;
}

img.thumb height{
  width:auto;
  height:200px;
  border:0px;
}
```

I would prefer not to, but do I need to use JQuery instead (e.g. find image width and length, if width > length then add "width" to class)

Comment: What are your rules for determining how to resize? Like if the image has larger width, what is the expected behavior and vice-versa? And what should happen if the width and height are the same?

Comment: @Mikey Thank you for commenting. To begin with, the width and height will not be the same (this is definite). I'm trying to create 2 rules for re-size. A) when width is longer than height, re-size width to 200px and height as auto. Vice-versa B) for height. Since I'm not sure how to go about "determine which width or height is longer", I re-size it to fixed width:200px; height:150px at the moment.

Comment: What you are looking for is `object-fit` - not supported in all browsers yet, but there's workarounds. If you're o.k. with making them background images instead, `background-size` can be used to the same effect (and browser support is much higher.)

Comment: @CBroe, thank you for your comment and suggestion. I'm not familiar with background images and background-fit. Can you kindly give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this can be achieved purely by CSS.

```css
.thumb {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.thumb img {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumb">
  <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30527718/tall.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="thumb">
  <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30527718/wide.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Or [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/Dottenpixel/pen/RRNqMK)

Comment: Good idea! With `display:inline-flex` don't work in Firefox and IE but with table-cell or float works fine in all browser.

Comment: @Lounge, thank you very much. It works!! But I have a problem, it won't align to the center like yours. What maybe the problem? https://jsfiddle.net/2tc5Lh3m/

Comment: if you use `flex` or  `inline-flex`  center the elements with `justify-content:center;`

Comment: @Maki, my pleasure! Glad to help. In your fiddle you were missing `margin: auto` on your `<img>` tags. [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2tc5Lh3m/3/)

Comment: @Lounge9, awesome. Thanks for the follow up on the extra question. After trial-and-error, I found out that I need to put the 'margin: auto' at ' a href' which I didn't wrote in the demo. '<div><a href><img src>' By the way, how come margin is effecting it?

Comment: @Maki correct, whatever the direct parent is of the <img> needs to have all the `display: inline-flex, width, height, etc`. Essentially [this is how I'd do it](https://jsfiddle.net/2tc5Lh3m/4/). Also, this is a great explanation of [margin:auto works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3170774/390866)

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to do this.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_methods.asp

```
var thumbImage = document.getElementById("your-image-id").style ;
//Your calculation in some variable x , y
var thumbImage.width = x ;
var thumbImage.height = y ;
```